# Blocking in java

Tags: java, android, blocking

I have an app in which I need to block all network activity until one particular process is completed. After that, all threads should be free to perform their network activity at will. Blocking is a bit of a weak point for me, and I'm uncertain if I'm doing it right. I believe what I have will work, but my gut instinct tells me that I shouldn't be doing it this way.

```
public static class BlockingClass implements ReentrantLock
{
    private static BlockingClass sBlockingClass = new BlockingClass();

    static
    {
        sBlockingClass.lock();
    }


    public void ProcessThatNeedsToWait()
    {
        while(sBlockingClass.isLocked());

        Continue();
    }


    public void ProcessThatNeedsToBeWaitedFor()
    {
         DoInitWork();

         sBlockingClass.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd use one of the `java.util.concurrent` classes, [such as `CountDownLatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: Can you give more input on how you get access to network? Perhaps it is a solution to implement a ConnectionPool which blocks aquiring a network connection when a special thread aquires a connection.

Comment: @CommonsWare I went with a java.util.concurrent.Phaser. In the onAdvance, I basically just return {first thread completed}, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! ^_^

Comment: @MartinKruger Thanks for your suggestion, but that solution is not quite sufficient. That solution would allow me to block once the initializing thread has started, but what about before it has started? I still need the network threads to wait until the initializing thread was finished, regardless of whether the initializer has started or not.

Comment: @KairisCharm: I don't know what your `minSdkVersion` is, but I think `Phaser` is new to API Level 21 or so.

Comment: Well, the Phaser is Java 7, which I believe has been in use since..... KitKat? I could be wrong. But our minSdkVersion is 21

Answer (score 0):

As per now you are using 'busy waiting' with that "while(...) continue"

A better solution will probabley be implementing your task as runnables and 
placing them in one manager class, pass a callback to the first task and add every new task to a list inside the manager (that is while the callback did not return yet) as soon as the callback return traverse the list and start every runnable with it's own thread.

ofcourse that solution only applies by what I could understand from the problem you are facing, in case it dosent fit add some more details\code so I can understand better what you are trying to solve.